# Inheritting from ListViewItemCollection

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to create a class that inherits from ListViewItemCollection, and I got this error: "No overload for method 'ListViewItemCollection' takes '0' arguments".

Any idea how to fix it or how I can inherit from this class. All suggestions are welcome. Greetings!

Comment: I can tell right away that it is a problem with your contructor....however, could you post your derived class code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frederik's answer is correct, ListViewItemCollection class needs an owner i.e. a ListView object to be passed in to the constructor.

However, I think his declaration is wrong, you may need to do:

```
public class MyListViewItemCollection : ListView.ListViewItemCollection
{
    public MyListViewItemCollection(ListView owner)
        : base(owner)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed; ListViewItemCollection is declared inside the ListView class.
My code however, was written directly in the SO editor, so I haven't verified it with the compiler or whatsoever.
Anyway, I've adapted it. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the ListViewItemCollection class does not have a public default constructor.

This means that you will have to explicitly create a constructor in your class, which calls one of the accessible (protected or public) constructors in the ListViewItemCollection class.

The ListViewItemCollection class does have a public constructor which takes a ListView as an argument.

So, your class could look like this:

```
public class MyListViewItemCollection : ListView.ListViewItemCollection
{
     public MyListViewItemCollection ( ListView owner ) : base(owner)
     {}
}
```

edit: The constructor which takes a ListView as an argument, is the only constructor that is accessible, so you'll have to do it like my example above.

Comment: The ListViewItemCollection is declared inside the ListView type, so you will need to include that in the declaration: "ListView.ListViewItemCollection" instead of "ListViewItemCollection".